# How do I use pandas to perform a mongodB $lookup and $unwind?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a dataframe df1 as follows,

```
ID     email        status         ID2
10   a@gmail.com   completed       12
11   b@gmail.com   not_completed   10
12   c@gmail.com   completed       11
13   d@gmail.com   completed       12
```

How do I perform the following MongoDB pipeline using Pandas,

```
{ $lookup: { 'from': 'df1', 'localField': 'ID', 'foreignField': 'ID2', 'as': 'member' } }
```

Then, next step is to unwind,

```
{ $unwind: { path: '$member' } },
```

The required output would look something like this.

```
ID2     email        status        member
10   a@gmail.com   completed      [{ID: 11, email: 'b@gmail.com', status: 'not_completed'}]  
11   b@gmail.com   not_completed  [{ID: 12, email: 'c@gmail.com', status: 'completed'}]
12   c@gmail.com   completed      [{ID: 10, email: 'a@gmail.com', status: 'completed'}]
12   c@gmail.com   completed      [{ID: 13, email: 'd@gmail.com', status: 'completed'}]
```

Comment: your best bet is to post your expected final output

Comment: @sammywemmy added my expected output